# Projection of vector onto intersection of two planes

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given that $U$ is a vector space in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ there exists  a unique vector $\mathbf{u_{0}}$ such that
$$\left \| \mathbf{v}-\mathbf{u_{0}} \right \|\leq \left \| \mathbf{v}-\mathbf{u} \right \|$$ where  $\mathbf{v} \notin U $

Given this information I am trying to find $\mathbf{u_{0}}$ where:

$U$ is the plane $x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}=0$, $x_{1}-x_{2}+x_{3}-x_{4}=0$ and $\mathbf{v}=(1,0,0,0)$. My method is to find the plane of intersection and then project $\mathbf{v}$ onto the plane to give $\mathbf{u_{0}}$. I took the orthonormal basis for the plane of intersection as:

$$ \left \{ \mathbf{u_{1}}=(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},0,-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},0), \mathbf{u_{2}}=(0,\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},0,-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}) \right \} $$

This gives me  $\mathbf{u_{0}}= (\mathbf{v},\mathbf{u_{1}})\mathbf{u_{1}} +(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{u_{2}})\mathbf{u_{2}}=(\frac{1}{2},0,-\frac{1}{2},0)$ which lies in $U$ as expected, but wouldn't $\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{u_{0}}$ be normal to the planes which defines $U$?

Comment: $v-u_0$ is normal to the intersection of hyperplanes, not necessarily to any of them.

Comment: Oh ok, it is quite hard to think about 4D planes but I think I can see a 3D analogue that makes sense relative to your comment, thanks

Comment: In $3D$ consider $U$ defined by the intersection of $x=0$ and $y=0$ and $v=(1,1,1).$ Then, $u_0=(0,0,1)$ and $v-u_0=(1,1,0),$ which is not perpendicular to $x=0$ nor $y=0.$